# why if change manufacturing of a product not change the price for the buyer?

Tags: business

I want to explain my question, if it is true.
Take an example, "X".
"X" wants to move their production from a country to another, doing that, "X" reducing the cost of manufacturing that product. But "X" decides not to change the price for the buyer.
So, why if "X" pays less for manufacturing a product the buyer has to pay the same as before?

Maybe is a stupid question but I'm curious. 
Thanks.

Comment: They pocket the difference, that's why so many manufacturing are doing this. It's probably the bigger change they can make that influence their profit margin.

Comment: Price is about what someone can and will pay, not what something costs to make.  When I buy a pen I'm not concerned with the fact that it contains about $0.0003 worth of plastic, then pen is worth $1 to me because that's what I could buy a comparable pen for.  I can't go home and fashion my own pen for less than $1 so regardless of the actual cost to manufacture the pen I am still better off buying one for $1.

Answer (score 1):

In highly developed and competitive industries companies tread a continuous and very fine line between maximising shareholder profits by keeping prices up while making products as cheaply as possible, vs competitors lowering prices when they work out a way to make equivalents cheaper.

In the short run you will quite often see companies hold onto large portions of efficiency savings (particularly if they make a major breakthrough in a specific manufacturing process etc) by holding old prices up, but in the long run competition pretty quickly lowers prices as the companies trying to keep high margins and prices get ruthlessly undercut by smaller competitors happy to make a bit less.